# How String is immutable?

Tags: java, string, immutability

If a `String` object is immutable then why is it printing "Help"?

The String object `s1` shouldn't be modified according to its immutability feature. I am confused for years, please help me understand this:

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "Hello";

    s1 = "Help";

    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

**Output**

```
Help
```

Comment: The assignment `s1="Help";` creates a new object in the string pool and assigns the reference to `s1`.  The original `"Hello"` string in the pool has not been modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second assignment actually is changing the `String` that s1 references.

There is still a `String` of "Hello" in existence (in the pool) which cannot be changed.

The behavior you described would be achieved by making s1 `final` - in which case you would get a compiler error if you tried to change the value the String s1 references.